# Count using letters

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

### What to do?

Starting from `a`, count in the sequence:

```
a, b, c, d, ... , y, z, aa, ab, ac, ... , ay, az, ba, bb, bc, ... , zy, zz, aaa, aab, aac, ... , zzy, zzz, aaaa, aaab, aaac, ...
```

### Input

The input, `n`, will an integer representing how far to count.

### Output

The output should be `n` space-separated strings following the above counting sequence.

---

### Example

Note: some strings are removed from the output to be concise.

```
Input -> Output
15 -> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
100 -> a b c d ... cs ct cu cv
1000 -> a b c d ... ali alj alk all
10000 -> a b c d ... ntm ntn nto ntp
100000 -> a b c d ... eqxa eqxb eqxc eqxd
```

Comment: A nicely written first challenge, but one we've already had.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A bit of a shame about the duplication, it's a nicely laid out challenge. We have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to test the waters and iron out problems as well; hopefully you enjoy your time here! :-)